# Magento Attribute Group - pseudocode for display data in a table using foreach?

Tags: php, html, magento

The thing I want is bit difficult to explain. So apologies for any confusion. I am retrieving a group of attributes (16 in total) that I have created for my product. And this 16 attributes can be divided into 4 columns (A, B, C, D) based on the type. So I want to create a table with A, B, C, D as heading. Then I want to display the label and data for the relevant column. The following will give you an idea what I want.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>heading-A</td>
<td>heading-B</td>
<td>heading-C</td>
<td>heading-D</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>label-A</td>
<td>Data-A</td>
<td>label-B</td>
<td>Data-B</td>
<td>label-C</td>
<td>Data-C</td>
<td>Label-D</td>
<td>Data-D</td>
</tr>
<tr>...and so on
</table
```

*Don't worry about putting label-A and Data-A under heading-A. I can achieve that using CSS.

I know I can do this by calling the attribute name directly (i.e. $_product->getAttribute) in each relevant table. But the problem is there are couple of attribute sets and each one has different attributes (i.e. 16 attribute group is different for each set).

So instead of creating a huge table and calling value individually I am trying to achieve this using a pseudocode which will be much simpler and smart way for doing that.

So far I have tried like this:

```
$attributes = $_product->getAttributes();
<table>
<tr>
<td>Sight</td>
<td>Nose</td>
<td>Palate</td>
<td>Finish</td>
</tr>
<?php foreach($attributes as $attribute):?>
                    <?php if($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() && $attribute->getIsUserDefined()):?>
                        <tr>
                            <?php if(stripos($attribute->getAttributeCode(), "_sight")!=0):?><td><th class="data"><?php echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel(); ?></th></td>
                            <td class="data"><?php echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); continue;?></td><?php endif; ?>

                            <?php if(stripos($attribute->getAttributeCode(), "_nose")!=0): ?><td><th class="data"><?php echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel(); ?></th></td>
                            <td class="data"><?php echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); continue;?></td><?php endif; ?>

                            <?php if(stripos($attribute->getAttributeCode(), "_palate")!=0): ?><td><th class="data"><?php echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel(); ?></th></td>
                            <td class="data"><?php echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); continue;?></td><?php endif;?>

                            <?php if(stripos($attribute->getAttributeCode(), "_finish")!=0): ?><td><th class="data"><?php echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel(); ?></th></td>
                            <td class="data"><?php echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); continue;?></td><?php endif;?>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

But this is giving me output all in a single column. I am not sure how to separate them into 4 columns the way I want. Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

continue will stop the loop and go on to the next iteration.

You have 4 columns of heading and 8 columns of data.

<th> is for heading cells http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_th.asp

So I hope the following is more towards your solution.

```
$attributes = $_product->getAttributes();
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">Sight</td>
<td colspan="2">Nose</td>
<td colspan="2">Palate</td>
<td colspan="2">Finish</td>
</tr>

<?php foreach($attributes as $attribute):
  if($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() && $attribute->getIsUserDefined()):?>
      <tr>
          <?php if(stripos($attribute->getAttributeCode(), "_sight")!=0) { ?>
              <td class="label"><?php echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel();          ?></td>
              <td class="data"><?php  echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?></td>
          <?php } else { ?>
              <td class="label"></td>
              <td class="data"></td>
          <?php } ?>

          <?php if(stripos($attribute->getAttributeCode(), "_nose")!=0) { ?>
              <td class="label"><?php echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel();          ?></td>
              <td class="data"><?php  echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?></td>
          <?php } else { ?>
              <td class="label"></td>
              <td class="data"></td>
          <?php } ?>

          <?php if(stripos($attribute->getAttributeCode(), "_palate")!=0) { ?>
              <td class="label"><?php echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel();          ?></td>
              <td class="data"><?php  echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?></td>
          <?php } else { ?>
              <td class="label"></td>
              <td class="data"></td>
          <?php } ?>

          <?php if(stripos($attribute->getAttributeCode(), "_finish")!=0) { ?>
              <td class="label"><?php echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel();         ?></td>
              <td class="data"><?php  echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);?></td>
          <?php } else { ?>
              <td class="label"></td>
              <td class="data"></td>
          <?php } ?>
      </tr>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```